# how to specify cucumber tags as invocation param in eclipse debug configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, cucumber, bdd

I have a Spring Boot project. In it I have a java class BookTests which contains:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/acceptance-test-report",
                "json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json"
        },
        glue = {
                "com.my.sdk.test",
                "com.my.book.test"
        }
        ,tags = {"@findConsideringGrants"}
        )
public class BookTests {
    // No implementation required.  The Cucumber annotations drive the test execution.

}
```

I'm using Junit 4. when I "Debug As JUnit Test" this class it only runs the  feature file which is annotated with "@findConsideringGrants (as it should)

Is there a way i don't have to hard-code this tags annotation in the java class but instead specify the tags as Program argumnents or VM arguuments?

I tried configuring it with Program argumnents, but with all the following attempts it ignored the argument and ran the tests on all my features/tags:

```
--tags findConsideringGrants 
-tags findConsideringGrants
--tags @findConsideringGrants 
-tags @findConsideringGrants
```

So to summerize, i'm looking for a way to
1) debug in eclipse a certain feature
2) without hardcoding the name of the feature into the java source. Somehow by just configuring the debug configuration.

is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using maven you can use -- `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @findConsideringGrants"`.

Or you can use the cucumber cli command to run -- `Main.main(new String[]{"-g", "classpath to step definition file","-t", "tags to use", "-p", "plugins to use", "Full path to feature file"})`.  The feature file path has to be the last option.

Running from eclipse --
Go to the "Environment" tab of the "Debug Configurations" or "Run Configurations" window. Click on "New" button. For the "Name" add "`cucumber.options`" and "Value" add "`--tags @findConsideringGrants`". Apply and Run. If you want to add a specific feature file path add only the path to the end of this.

Comment: thanks but i'm looking for a way to 1) debug in eclipse a certain feature 2) without hardcoding the name of the feature into the java source. Somehow by just configuring the debug configuration

Comment: @inor Added eclipse way of adding environment variables

Comment: thanks. that's what i was looking for. gave you the credit :-)